# overriding same class method at run-time c++

Tags: c++

say I have a class like this in c++:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        int MyMethod1 (/*Some Cool Args*/)
        {
            //do something
        }
        int MyMethod2 (/*More Args*/)
        {
            //do something
        }
        .
        .
        .
        int MyMethodN (/*More Args*/)
        {
            //do something
        }
}
```

now, lets say that depending on the state of the object at runtime, I need to use either MyMethode1, MyMethode2, ..., or MyMethodeN, which all do basically the same but change the way they do it based on the object state at run-time.

*So, my question is*: Is there a way to have something like...

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        int MyMethod (/*Some Cool Args*/)
        {
            //do something in consideration to the current object state
        }
}
```

Basically what I mean is if a polymorphic behavior can be achieved within a same class without having to call derived objects or use pointers to member methods or have a sequence of ifs or a switch

Comment: Logic to do "stuff based on state" has to exist somewhere...

Comment: Avoid tons of functions that basically do the same thing but change the way they do it. Make objects and use dynamic dispatch.

Comment: You need a dispatch table, often just a humble `switch` statement.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ double dispatch" and "c++ dispatch".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the case you describe is not a very good case for polymorphism. I think you should consider using Composition along with the Strategy pattern.

This concept is where you encapsulate some work or algorithm in a function or callable object, of which you have several, then choose which one to use based on the parents state. You can hold a reference to a pointer or callable object (functor) in a std::function, which can be a member of the parent class.

Or, even more simply, if the system doesn't call for such complexity, you have member functions which contain each method for resolving the new input, and choose which one to use with if statements.